# CircleCI forgetting node version on machine executor

Tags: node.js, circleci, nvm

I'm setting the node version to `10.15.1` with `nvm` and in the next `run` step it's back to `6.1.0`. I've tried several variations including this one : https://www.cloudesire.com/how-to-upgrade-node-on-circleci-machine-executor/

Am I missing something obvious? I just need each `run` step to remember the node version I set in the first one so they will all use `10.15.1` in this case.

Here is the job in my workflow:

```
dev:
  environment:
    BASH_ENV: run/env/test/.env
  machine:
    image: circleci/classic:latest
  steps:
  - checkout
  - run:
      name: Install node@10
      command: |
        set +e

        curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
        export NVM_DIR="/opt/circleci/.nvm"
        [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

        nvm install 10
        nvm alias default 10

        rm -rf ~./node-gyp

        node -v # prints 10.15.1 as expected

  - run:
      name: Install yarn and rsync
      command: |
        node -v # prints 6.1.0

        export NVM_DIR="/opt/circleci/.nvm"
        [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

        node -v # prints 6.1.0

        curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
        echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
        sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn rsync

  - run:
      name: Install node modules
      command: |
        node -v # prints 6.1.0

        yarn install # this is what is failing because of the unexpected node version

  - run:
      name: Deploy to Dev Server
      command: |
        if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "master" ]; then rsync -arhvz --exclude .git/ -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" --progress \
        ./ ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/www/xxx/xxx/; fi
        if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "master" ]; then ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cd /var/www/xxx/xxx && pm2 restart all --update-env'; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding installed node to $PATH

Example:

```
    - run:
        name: 'Install Project Node'
        command: |
          set +x
          source ~/.bashrc

          nvm install 12
          NODE_DIR=$(dirname $(which node))
          echo "export PATH=$NODE_DIR:\$PATH" >> $BASH_ENV
```

Answer (score 1):

@FelicianoTech is incorrect, every single build step runs in a fresh environment and forgets your nvm settings. You have to set NVM_DIR and source the nvm setup script in every single build step. Annoying, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Despite that FelicianoTech is correct, that in the machine executor you have nvm preinstalled, it does not remember the actual state in the next run command. In order to make nvm remember its state you have to store it in the `$BASH_ENV`. Searching hours long, I finally found an [answer in the CircleCI Disussion Board](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/nvm-does-not-change-node-version-on-machine/28973/9):

```
machine: 
      image: circleci/classic:latest
steps:
      - checkout
      - run: 
          command: |
            echo 'export NVM_DIR="/opt/circleci/.nvm"' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo ' [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' >> $BASH_ENV
      - run: nvm install 10
      - run: node -v
      - run: npm -v
      - run: npm i -g npm@6.9.0
      - run: npm -v
      - run: nvm alias default 10
      - run: nvm use 10
      - run: node -v
      - run: npm -v
```

Then, and only then, I had success as well that even the last run command `- run: node -v` still remembers the node version properly.

The output on CircleCI

[image]

*(Credits to phil-lgr on the discussion board)*

Answer (score 0):

You're doing way too much here. All you need to do is run `nvm install v10`. `nvm` is already installed in the `machine` executor.